# Why Tensor must be Integer in Pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch

I want to get my accuracy. So I divide the correct number(tensor) by the total number(tensor). Then I get a integrate instead of a float. I wonder why. The code is as follows. Also, if I transfer tensor to numpy, why I cannot get an exact number? I get description like `"built-in method numpy of Tensor object at 0x00000296AEDC1168"` I still do not know the exact number.

I tried tensor.numpy

```
print(correct)
tensor(9668)

print(total)
10000

print(correct/total)
tensor(0)

print(100 * correct/total)
tensor(96)

print((100 * correct/total).numpy)
<built-in method numpy of Tensor object at 0x00000296AEDC1168>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert to a floating type using `.float()` for `correct` or `total`. Like so:

```
correct.float()/total
```

> Also, if I transfer tensor to numpy, why I cannot get an exact number?

The correct way to convert to numpy is `.numpy()`. In your case:

```
(100 * correct/total).numpy()
```

Comment: Thanks! but I'm not sure why the output of .numpy is like <built-in method numpy of Tensor object at 0x00000296AEDC1168>, not directly a number. How to view this number?

Comment: `.numpy` is the reference to the function. You need to call it using `.numpy()`. It's the same as if you tried to run `print` instead of `print()`.